# glide update failing -> Unable to export dependencies to vendor directory: Error moving files: exit status 1. output: Access is denied. 0 dir(s) moved

Tags: go, glide-golang

I followed the [tutorial for glide usage](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide).
I did `glide init` and a `glide.yaml` was created successfully. Post that, when I did `glide update`, I am getting below error. Any idea how do I resolve this?

I installed `glide` using `go get github.com/Masterminds/glide`

Note: I am doing these operation on `Windows` via `Git Bash` terminal.

(Not sure, but if `GOPATH` value is required, it is `/c/Users/aagoyal/eclipse-workspace-oxygen/GoPath/:/d/Edge_OSS/code/microservice/NE3SProto/`. And my code is in location `/d/DAAAS/Edge_OSS/code/microservice/NE3SProto/src/ne3s`)

```
$ glide update
[INFO]  Downloading dependencies. Please wait...
[INFO]  --> Fetching updates for github.com/gorilla/mux
[INFO]  Resolving imports
[INFO]  --> Fetching updates for github.com/gorilla/context
[INFO]  Downloading dependencies. Please wait...
[INFO]  Setting references for remaining imports
[INFO]  Exporting resolved dependencies...
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/gorilla/context
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/gorilla/mux
[INFO]  Replacing existing vendor dependencies
[ERROR] Unable to export dependencies to vendor directory: Error moving files: exit status 1. output: Access is denied.
        0 dir(s) moved.
```

Comment: There's also a [bug report on glide's GitHub page](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide/issues/873) regarding the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting the same error when running Glide on Windows in an automated build environment. It seemed to be a problem moving the files from whatever temp directory Glide was using into the final vendor directory.

For me, I was able to get around the issue by overriding the `GLIDE_TMP` environment variable such that it was located in my project's build directory. So, in your case, you can try either setting the `GLIDE_TMP` variable to a working directory near your project directory, or using the `glide --tmp value` argument to do so just once as part of each Glide command

e.g. (assuming Bash terminal):

```
GLIDE_TMP=/d/DAAAS/Edge_OSS/code
glide update
```

or

```
glide --tmp /d/DAAAS/Edge_OSS/code update
```

If that temp directory doesn't work, you could instead try using your `/d/DAAAS/Edge_OSS/code/microservice/NE3SProto/src/ne3s` project directory as the temp directory, in which case Glide will temporarily create a random `glide-vendor1234567` subdirectory there until it moves the files to `vendor`.